# Login page Re-Routing in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, routes

Is there any way to re-route the user to the homepage, suppose the user gets logged in by using user credentials but when he presses the back button he again navigates to the login page (which I don't want), new to angular any suggestions?

Comment: You can add a redirection on your **/loginPage**, by adding  a guard to check if the user is already logged  redirect to **/homePage** if not show the **/loginPage**

Comment: Already tried using guard but got this, R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Router GuardService -> LoginModule Component -> LoginModule Component -> LoginModule Component]: NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginModuleComponent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some examples for authguards:

https://www.positronx.io/protect-angular-2-routes-with-canactivate-guard-for-firebase-users/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dHcPlXJIvs

Hopefully, that will help you :) Ive watched all the videos on youtube regarding the auth guard. It's not that hard but a very nice feature.

Don't forget to add the guard into your NgModule class as an **"provider"**...

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [AuthGuard], <------
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a canActivate guard to check if the user is loggedIn or not.
lets call it AnonymousGuard.
you can generate one by 'ng g guard anonymous'.

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      // already logged in so return false
      this.router.navigate('/home');
      return false;
    }
    // not logged in so return true
    return true;
  }
```

And where you are defining the route for login page, o something like this

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AnonymousGuard]
   },
```

Comment: You can check the following for a better understanding
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/